# How do I reconnect the bones within parented armatures?

Tags: rigging

I needed several armatures parented to each other in my skeleton, but now all the bones are disconnected.Basically (dont laugh, i needed armatures to each bone :), one armature parents the other and i wanted to reconnect the bones. How can I do that? under the bone tab, relations, parent is disabled. please tell me I can do that....

Comment: Is there a reason for needing separate armatures? Could you simply join them together? There is a question that details that method here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44502/joining-two-rigged-models

Comment: Brenticus!!! It was so awesome that you suggested!!!! I think I might have to expl,ain a little better:

Comment: Brenticus!!! It was so awesome that you suggested!!!! I think I might have to explain a little better: 1) i have a skeleton that was skinned and rigged - one armature; 2) i read somewhere here that i could converted the bones to have its own armature, so i did that; 3) it was all good until i found out the bones were no longer connected; all i need is to find a way to re-parent the bones between different armatures. AGAIN THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR TAKING YOUR TIME!! THANK YOU!

Comment: If all of your bones are separate and different objects in object mode I would recommend combining them with Ctrl-J and going that route. If you need the Armatures to be separate, then you can Parent an armature to the bone of another armature with Ctrl-P and choosing bone (Note: the armature you are parenting to must be in pose mode so you can select the right bone to parent to).